# The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint on my asp.net app

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have problem with my first web application , when I start the application Im getting this error:

[1st img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbHFO.png)

[2nd img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwgcW.png)

The application is about car rental.

1.I will show my data structure: for CarCategory and SmallCars

--CARCATEGORY

```
namespace CarRentalSystem.Data.Models
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using CarRentalSystem.Data.Common.Models;

    public class CarCategory : BaseDeletableModel<int>
    {
        public CarCategory()
        {
            this.SmallCars = new HashSet<SmallCarInfo>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string CarDescription { get; set; }

        public string CarImageUrl { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SmallCarInfo> SmallCars { get; set; }
    }
}
```

--SMALLCARS

```
namespace CarRentalSystem.Data.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    using CarRentalSystem.Data.Common.Models;

    public class SmallCarInfo : BaseModel<int>
    {
        public string CarModel { get; set; }

        public string CarImage { get; set; }

        public int CarPricePerDay { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual CarCategory Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2. Now I make a migration and im going to make two SEEDERS with data:

--CAR CATEGORIES SEEDER

```
namespace CarRentalSystem.Data.Seeding
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using CarRentalSystem.Data.Models;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;

    public class CategoriesSeeder : ISeeder
    {
        public async Task SeedAsync(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (dbContext.CarCategories.Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            var carCategories = new List<(string Name, string ImageUrl, string CarDescription)>
            {
                ("Small car", "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/car-silhouettes/1000/city-car-128.png",
                    "This is a compact car with 2/3 doors. Perfect for couples with small luggage."),
                ("Medium car", "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/car-silhouettes/1000/sedan-128.png",
                    "This is medium car with 4/5 doors. Perfect for small families with average luggage."),
                ("Minivan", "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/car-silhouettes/1000/minivan-128.png",
                    "This is a large car with 4/5 doors + extra seats. Perfect for large families with average luggage."),
                ("Minibus", "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/car-silhouettes/1000/van-128.png",
                    "This is a large car with 8+1 seats with big trunk. Perfect for large families or companies with a lot of luggage"),
            };

            foreach (var category in carCategories)
            {
                await dbContext.CarCategories.AddAsync(new CarCategory
                {
                    Name = category.Name,
                    Title = category.Name,
                    CarImageUrl = category.ImageUrl,
                    CarDescription = category.CarDescription,
                });
            }

            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

--SMALL CARS SEEDER

```
namespace CarRentalSystem.Data.Seeding
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using CarRentalSystem.Data.Models;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;

    public class SmallCarsSeeder : ISeeder
    {
        public async Task SeedAsync(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (dbContext.SmallCar.Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            var carDetails = new List<(string CarModel, string CarImage, int CarPricePerDay)>
            {
                ("Nissan Micra", "https://5.imimg.com/data5/BV/XC/RV/SELLER-85643879/nissan-micra-xl-o-cvt-turquoise-blue-1198-cm3-car-500x500.jpg", 15),
                ("Ford Fiesta", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT_s9VktREdvkJUF9uU2V4NWIOzxU4Olk8IdTO2DOfjbAnsJQcU&usqp=CAU", 15),
            };

            foreach (var details in carDetails)
            {
                await dbContext.SmallCar.AddAsync(new SmallCarInfo
                {
                    CarModel = details.CarModel,
                    CarImage = details.CarImage,
                    CarPricePerDay = details.CarPricePerDay,
                });
            }

            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

3.Now Im making CONTROLLERS + SERVICES/VIEW-MODELS and VIEWS

--CONTROLLER FOR CHOOSING SMALL CARS

```
namespace CarRentalSystem.Web.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using CarRentalSystem.Data.Models;
    using CarRentalSystem.Services.Data;
    using CarRentalSystem.Web.ViewModels.Categories;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    public class CategoriesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICategoriesService categoriesService;

        public CategoriesController(ICategoriesService categoriesService)
        {
            this.categoriesService = categoriesService;
        }

        public IActionResult ChooseCars(string name)
        {
             var viewModel =
                this.categoriesService.GetByName<CarsListViewModel>(name);

             return this.View(viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

--"GetByName" SERVICE LOGIC

```
namespace CarRentalSystem.Services.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    public interface ICategoriesService
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(int? count = null);

        T GetByName<T>(string name);
    }
}


namespace CarRentalSystem.Services.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    using CarRentalSystem.Data.Common.Repositories;
    using CarRentalSystem.Data.Models;
    using CarRentalSystem.Services.Mapping;

    public class CategoriesService : ICategoriesService
    {
        private readonly IDeletableEntityRepository<CarCategory> categoriesRepository;

        public CategoriesService(IDeletableEntityRepository<CarCategory> categoriesRepository)
        {
            this.categoriesRepository = categoriesRepository;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(int? count = null)
        {
            IQueryable<CarCategory> query =
                this.categoriesRepository.All();
            if (count.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Take(count.Value);
            }

            return query.To<T>().ToList();
        }

        public T GetByName<T>(string name)
        {
            var category = this.categoriesRepository.All()
                .Where(x => x.Name.Replace(" ", "-") == name.Replace(" ", "-"))
                .To<T>().FirstOrDefault();

            return category;
        }
    }
}
```

-- TWO VIEW-MODELS THAT GET DATA FROM DATA MODELS AND MAPPING

```
namespace CarRentalSystem.Web.ViewModels.Categories
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    using CarRentalSystem.Data.Models;
    using CarRentalSystem.Services.Mapping;

    public class CarsListViewModel : IMapFrom<CarCategory>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string CarDescription { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<CarsViewModel> SmallCars { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace CarRentalSystem.Web.ViewModels.Categories
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    using CarRentalSystem.Data.Models;
    using CarRentalSystem.Services.Mapping;

    public class CarsViewModel : IMapFrom<SmallCarInfo>
    {
        public string CarModel { get; set; }

        public string CarImage { get; set; }

        public int CarPricePerDay { get; set; }
    }
}
```

--THE VIEW WITH RAZOR

```
@using CarRentalSystem.Common
@model CarRentalSystem.Web.ViewModels.Categories.CarsListViewModel
@{
    this.ViewData["Title"] = "Cars";
}

<h1 class="display-3">@Model.Title</h1>

<div class="row">
    @foreach (var details in Model.SmallCars)
    {
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="@details.CarImage" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">@details.CarModel</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">@details.CarPricePerDay euro.</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="card-body">
                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

4. And now when I start the app Im getting the error that I showed at the top.

[Picture of the CARCATEGORY table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y14D.png)

[Picture of the SMALLCARS table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAXix.png)

How can I fix the problem with FK confliction? Thanks!

Comment: At the first look You don't have in Your SmallCar table ForeignKey for category. You should use attribute at least in You model mapping to precise associations. So... [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))] on Category ins SmallCarInfo class

Comment: Can you show what is in your `OnModelCreating` method for SmallCars? The principal problem I can see is that you never set this value when you create a small car (only name, price per day, and image). Since CategoryId it is a non nullable int, it will default to 0, which is not a valid category ID. Although, I am not particularly au fait with migrations, so I am not sure whether this would be relevant when actually updating the database to match the model.

Comment: It is probably better to run an Alter Table from the SQL query than try to do with c#.  Even after doing the Alter Table from SSMS I found I had to close SSMS and open before c# would recognize the changes.